# Select elements from nested list where one element is largest

Tags: pattern-matching, filtering

I'm trying to speed up the following, but implementing efficient pattern matching isn't intuitive to me yet, even with lots of examples.

I have a list of ((x1,y1,z1), (x2,y2,z2)) pairs, and I want to make a new list selecting the (x,y,z) from the pair where the z value is greatest. The following works, but is slow. What is an efficient way to do this?

```
points={
{{30.7058, -2326.85, 420000.}, {31.4061, -1391.63, 479968.}},
{{47.2775, -2326.72, 479960.}, {48.4709, -1391.63, 420090.}},
{{36.9202, -2326.81, 479968.}, {37.8054, -1391.65, 420000.}},
{{51.4203, -2326.67, 420090.}, {52.7372, -1391.6,  479908.}},
{{34.8488, -2326.83, 420090.}, {35.6723, -1391.65, 479968.}}
}
set1=Position[points[[;; , 1, 3]], s_ /; s >450000];
set2=Position[points[[;; , 2, 3]], s_ /; s >450000];
Join[Extract[points[[;;,1]],set1],Extract[points[[;;,2]],set2]]

{
{31.4061, -1391.63, 479968.},
{47.2775, -2326.72, 479960.},
{36.9202, -2326.81, 479968.},
{52.7372, -1391.6,  479908.},
{35.6723, -1391.65, 479968.}
}
```

In case it prompts an answer where I can get the right xyz values to start with, these pairs are the solutions of the intersection of a bunch of lines with a sphere, where all the lines intersect the sphere twice:

```
Solve[(x - x0)/mx == (y - y0)/my == (z - z0) / mz && (x - xs0)^2 + (y - ys0)^2 + (z - zs0)^2 == rs^2, {x, y, z}]
```

The solutions I need is sometimes the first or second one. If I include && z > 450000 in the Solve it also works, but solves much more slowly than without that, so I thought I should extract them after the Solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you were interested in an efficient solution. I think the following should be pretty efficient:

```
maxZ[pts_] := Total[
    pts Transpose[{#, 1-#}& @ UnitStep[pts . {0, 0, 1} . {1, -1}]],
    {2}
]
```

For your example:

```
maxZ[points]
```

> {{31.4061, -1391.63, 479968.}, {47.2775, -2326.72, 
>     479960.}, {36.9202, -2326.81, 479968.}, {52.7372, -1391.6, 
>     479908.}, {35.6723, -1391.65, 479968.}}

For a larger dataset:

```
SeedRandom[1];
pts = RandomReal[1, {10^6, 2, 3}];
r1 = maxZ[pts]; //AbsoluteTiming

r1[[;;10]]
```

> {0.266662, Null}
>
> {{0.817389, 0.11142, 0.789526}, {0.700474, 0.211826, 0.748657}, {0.422851, 
>     0.247495, 0.977172}, {0.128821, 0.306427, 0.712012}, {0.390582, 0.819967, 
>     0.325351}, {0.316876, 0.789804, 0.011978}, {0.391276, 0.458902, 
>     0.458845}, {0.481571, 0.738297, 0.203011}, {0.544772, 0.562659, 
>     0.767697}, {0.46418, 0.278197, 0.548402}}

Compare to J42161217's answer:

```
r2 = Last @ SortBy[#, Last]& /@ pts; //AbsoluteTiming
r2[[;;10]]
```

> {3.26462, Null}
>
> {{0.817389, 0.11142, 0.789526}, {0.700474, 0.211826, 0.748657}, {0.422851, 
>     0.247495, 0.977172}, {0.128821, 0.306427, 0.712012}, {0.390582, 0.819967, 
>     0.325351}, {0.316876, 0.789804, 0.011978}, {0.391276, 0.458902, 
>     0.458845}, {0.481571, 0.738297, 0.203011}, {0.544772, 0.562659, 
>     0.767697}, {0.46418, 0.278197, 0.548402}}

So, about an order of magnitude faster.

Comment: The more I see answers as useful as this, the more I realize I should spend more time formulating the question in a way to make it easier to search for topics in the future. This is the most appropriate answer to the question now. (sorry J42161217!)

Comment: @DrBubbles that's ok! Carl Woll always comes up with fast algorithms and comparisons. Although I was an order of magnitude faster at answering ;-)

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
Last@SortBy[#,Last]&/@points
```

> {{31.4061, -1391.63, 479968.},
>    {47.2775, -2326.72, 479960.},
>    {36.9202, -2326.81, 479968.},
>    {52.7372, -1391.6, 479908.},
>    {35.6723, -1391.65, 479968.}}

Answer (score 1):

One way is to Select the ones you want. You can Select by the maximum of each triplet

```
Select[Flatten[points, 1], Max[#] > 450000 &]

{{31.4061, -1391.63, 479968.}, {47.2775, -2326.72, 479960.}, 
 {36.9202, -2326.81, 479968.}, {52.7372, -1391.6, 479908.}, 
 {35.6723, -1391.65, 479968.}}
```

or by the third element explicitly:

```
Select[Flatten[points, 1], #[[3]] > 450000 &]
```

Comment: This and @J42161217 's answer are both much faster solutions than mine and are themselves similar in speed. So each is a great solution, I'll vote J42161217 's as the answer as it was first.  Real life examples like this are so useful for helping understand the syntax.